# Problems with lookup table in custom javascript

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have an issue using custom html(javascript) in GTM.

I'm firing a tag and one of the tag-attributes' values is found in a lookuptable variable.

When I let the tag fire, and I check the current state of the Datalayer & it's variables in GTM Debugger, the value is correct (corresponding to the inputvalue of the lookuptable), but the tag itself KEEPS firing the same value from the lookup table but not the correct one...

I'm using the `{{universe_id}}` syntax.

Clearing the cache does not solve the issue..

The lookup table variable in GTM:

[image: GTM]

The environment variable in GTM:

[image: GTM]

Essential part of the Custom JS Tag:

```
<script>  
var owner = {{dl_ctx_owner}};  
var env = {{dl_ctx_environment}}; 


if ((owner == "MY") && (env == "test" || env == "live" )) {

wa.bt_queue.push(
{
"universeId": {{id_bt_universe}},
...
```

After a certain datalayer.push where both environment & owner are filled in (checked it) and when the trigger fires:
When I check the datalayer variables , the id_bt_universe value is correct.
But not in the tag...

The current state of the used variable:

[image: Current state of universe id]

The call sent by the tag :

[image: call]

Comment: Can you show the configuration of {{dl_ctx_enviroment}} variable? And the Tag configuration? Also, what is the name of your lookup table variable?

Comment: The name of the lookuptable is {{id_bt_universe}}

Comment: The actual problem @Matus is that the only place where the value isn't correct is where I actually need it :P

Comment: can you share the setup of the tag that you are firing? Also, do you have a defult value for lookup table? When and how are you setting {{dl_ctx_environment}} variable ? There must a mistake with the setup somewhere because you should not have 2 different values for the same variable on a single event - it would be much easier to help you if you could share full setup of your tags and JS code.